# Postfix logs to remote log host

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, syslog, rsyslog, smtpd

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I'm using Postfix as a front-end mailserver, and I would like to send all mail related info, **including email addresses**, to a remote host. In the file */etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf* I have added the line:

```
*.*             @192.168.1.21
```

All syslog and smtpd related messages are send to the remote host, however, I'm missing the actual email addresses of the **postfix/smtp** transactions.

Are there special Postfix or Rsyslog configuration options to achieve this?

Comment: Can you give examples of what lines are making it to `192.168.1.21` and what lines aren't?

Comment: NOT send the the central log server:
`Mar 24 05:43:23 mail2 postfix/smtp[16412]: 2C52420134: to=<EMAILADDRESS@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27]:25, delay=0.57, delays=0/0/0.37/0.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1458794603 hh4si6961331wjc.172 - gsmtp)`

Comment: SEND to the syslog server:

`mail2 mail 05:43:23 smtp to=, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.27]:25, delay=0.57, delays=0/0/0.37/0.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1458794603 hh4si6961331wjc.172 - gsmtp)`